# In HERE API traffic flow data JSON response, What is the meaning of "SSS" and "SS' ? Where can I get complete list of meanings for JSON response?

Tags: here-api, jsonresponse, here-traffic

[Json response for traffic flow data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvX5f.jpg)

I tried to find meanings of acronyms of JSON response provided by HERE-API for traffic flow data. But couldn't find the meanings of "SSS" and "ss" and a complete list of meanings for JSON response. Please let me know any details that are available.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to HERE's meta resources document page to find the explanation for XSD schemas at https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/additional-parameters.html.

You can request the definition of acronyms based on the traffic or incidents API versions. For example below request will return a flow XSD:

[https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.0/xsd/flow.xsd?apiKey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)